# Store and go back to an Ember route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

On an Ember app, I am implementing a Wizard. It is composed of several steps (each step has its own route).

I want to store the route from which the user start the Wizard (with its model and query params if any).
At the end of the Wizard, I want to redirect the user to the initial route.

For example:

```
/myapp/some/route   --> click on a link to start the wizard
/myapp/wizard/step1
/myapp/wizard/step2
/myapp/wizard/step3 --> click to end the wizard
/myapp/some/route   --> the initial page
```

How can I do that?

In the `beforeModel(transition)` of the Wizard step 1, I found that:

- `this.get('router.currentRouteName')` give me the name of the previous route
- `this.modelFor(previousRoute)` give me the model
- `this.paramsFor(previousRoute)` give me the params

But, I do not find how to replay the transition backward, or to recreate a transition to go back to the initial route.

---

**Edit:** to add more context to the question

My router configuration:

```
Router.map(function () {
  ...    
  this.route('inbox', {
      path: '/inbox'
    },
    function () {
      this.route('msg', {path: '/msg'});
      this.route('encaissements', {path: '/encaissements'});
    }
  );
  ...
```

In wizard-route.js

```
  beforeModel(transition) {
    this._super(...arguments);

    let previousRoute = this.get('router.currentRouteName');
    if (previousRoute && previousRoute !== 'loading') {
      // store the previous route in the router
      this.set('router.previousRoute', previousRoute);
      this.set('router.previousModel', this.modelFor(previousRoute));
      this.set('router.previousParams', this.paramsFor(previousRoute));
    }
  }
  actions: {
    redirectToPreviousOrDefault(defaultRoute) {
      let previousRoute = this.get('router.previousRoute');
      if (previousRoute) {
        // a previous route exist, redirect !
        let previousModel = this.get('router.previousModel');
        let previousParams = this.get('router.previousParams');

        if (previousModel) {
          if (previousParams) {
            this.transitionTo(previousRoute, previousModel, previousParams);
          } else {
            this.transitionTo(previousRoute, previousModel);
          }
        } else if (previousParams) {
          this.transitionTo(previousRoute, previousParams);
        } else {
          this.transitionTo(previousRoute);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And at the end of the wizard, I call the action `redirectToPreviousOrDefault`.

```
this.get('router.previousRoute') --> inbox.msg
this.get('router.previousModel') --> undefined
this.get('router.previousParams') --> {}
```

So in this case, the line `this.transitionTo(previousRoute, previousParams);` is called. And produce this error:

Uncaught Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: inbox.msg

Comment: can you manually trigger a transition to the stored route along with the model and query params using `transitionTo` ?

Comment: I can't find a way to use `transitionTo` correctly. I update the question to reflect my last try.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is not that complex but comes down to `transionTo()`.

`transionTo()` could be a beast. It's arguments are highly dynamic. You could pass zero to unlimited models and an optional options hash. Models as well as options hash are objects. So it needs a more complex way to decide if last argument is a model or an options hash. To do so it checks if the object has a `queryParams` property. You are passing `{}`, which doesn't have that property and therefore is considered to be a model.

You could find more information about that implementation detail in source code: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v3.4.1/packages/ember-routing/lib/utils.js#L8-L22